# Однократно получить данные от функции

Tags: python, функции, время

Я работаю с двумя функциями, в первой я хочу получить актуальные данные, например о  стоимости валюты в ту минуту, в которую я ее (функцию) запустил. А во второй функции работать с теми однократно полученными данными.

Я приведу пример с функцией time

```
import time
def stop_time():
    t = time.time()
    return t

def my_data(old_time):
    print(int(time.time()) -int(old_time) )

for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(2)
    my_data(old_time=stop_time())
```

Я хочу, чтобы первая функция запомнила время, а вторая функция считала, сколько секунд прошло, вычитая сохраненное время из текущего. Но эта запись неверна, она все время вызывает актуальное время из функции stop_time().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [мемоизацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и в стандартной библиотеке есть [для этого средство](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def stop_time():
    t = time.time()
    return t
```

Answer (score 0):

Не проще так?

```
start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(2)
    my_data(old_time=start_time)
```

Comment: В вопросе просто пример. На самом деле функция может содержать 150 строк сложного кода и вызываться в десятке разных мест.